# Android Studio: Banner ad over Webview

Tags: android, webview, admob

how is it possible to add a Google Ad Banner over webview?
It should be displayd at the bottom and over webview not under.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="89dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="409dp"

    </WebView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your ConstraintLayout, to a RelativeLayout, and then just place the webview on top of the AdView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm sure you could keep the constraintlayout, but I like doing it the following way. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried your solution, but the ad still does not show up.

Comment: the ad doesn't show up at all? That maybe an issue you have with the a adview itself

Comment: Wait did you copy and paste your code exactly like it is in your IDE? Because if so, in the code you have, you didn't close the WebView tag

Comment: The ad works fine. When I delete the webview the ad shows up. But with the webview you can`t see it. I have closed the tag in my code, it was only a mistake.

Comment: Now it finally works, I dont relly know what the mistake was. When I run the app on the PC it shows the ad. But when I build an apk and try it on the phone the ad doesnt show up.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work when you do the APK is because there is a specific way to set it up for production. here is a link: http://thetechnocafe.com/a-complete-guide-to-integrating-admob-in-your-android-app/

Comment: Read through that and it should solve your problems for production, also accept the answer if it helped you :)